# Google sheets array arguments to countif are of different size

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, countif

```
=countifs(Kayan!F:F,$E$4,Kayan!K:K,F5,Kayan!L2:AP317,"true")
```

This formula returns an "array arguments to `countif` are of different size" error how do I fix it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try like this:

```
=COUNTIFS(Kayan!F:F, $E$4, Kayan!K:K, F5, Kayan!L:AP, "true")
```